# How to modify CSS property of element with container-type: inline-size by @container query

Tags: css, container-queries

I'm looking for solution how to modify property in css of element with `container-type: inline-size;` (not in children) by `@container` query.

Consider HTML

```
<div class="card card--1">
  <h2 class="card__title">
    card 1 title
  </h2>
  <p class="card__body">
    lorem ipsum
  </p>
</div>
<div class="card card--2">
  <h2 class="card__title">
    card 2 title
  </h2>
  <p class="card__body">
    lorem ipsum
  </p>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.card {
  container-type: inline-size;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}
.card--1 {
  width: 200px;
}
.card--2 {
  width: 300px;
}

@container (min-width: 250px) {
  .card {
    /* do not work */
    background-color: aqua;
  }
  .card__title {
    /* works fine */
    color: red;
  }
}
```

How to modify above example to change `background-color` in `.card` without changing HTML markup? Working example in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-jones-g9u2r8).

Comment: With container queries you cannot change the styles of the container element itself. You can only change the styles of the children 

Comment: @Boguz If it is official, find documentation for your claims, write answer with it and I will accept it.

Comment: yes, this is sadly official. I have added an answer for you, with a small example and some links with information

Comment: As @shiba has pointed out, elsewhere, `:container` would be a very useful addition to the spec, so that the container itself could be styled _within_ the `@container` query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Container queries are still an experimental features, not yet widely implemented.

With container queries you cannot change the styles of the container element itself. You can only change the styles of the children.

With css container queries we can define an element as a container. We will use that container in a sort of "media query". So you can then only style the element inside the "media query".

I wish it would be possible to style the container itself. this would be great for instance for webcomponents.

It is still possible to achieve what you want, but you need to add some extra markup. You need to add an extra "wrapper" inside you container.

So around your element, which already has your styles, add a new `div` (for instance `<div class="card-container">`, which will really only work as a container for your card. You can then in your css make that wrapper div your container and then style your card accordingly.

something like:

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card card--1">
    <h2 class="card__title">
      card 1 title
    </h2>
    <p class="card__body">
      lorem ipsum
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in your css:

```css
.card-container {
  container-type: inline-size;
}

@container (min-width: 250px) {
  .card {
    ...
  }
}
```

You can see how the browser support is here: https://caniuse.com/css-container-queries

There is some good information about it here:

- [Container queries on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries)
- [CSS container queries example on dev.top](https://dev.to/ingosteinke/a-css-container-queries-example-1le0)
- [Some more good examples here](https://ishadeed.com/article/container-queries-are-finally-here/)

Comment: > Container queries are still an experimental features, not yet widely implemented.

Per MDN it's a an experimental feature and per caniuse it is widely implemented.

Comment: i wish we could select the container itself, @container style() would be a cool alternative to mixins

Comment: @Shiba yes, me too!

Answer (score -1):

Use a pseudo element for this:

```css
.card {
  container-type: inline-size;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.card--1 {
  width: 200px;
}

.card--2 {
  width: 300px;
}

@container (min-width: 250px) {
  .card::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: aqua;
  }
  .card__title {
    /* works fine */
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card card--1">
  <h2 class="card__title">
    card 1 title
  </h2>
  <p class="card__body">
    lorem ipsum
  </p>
</div>
<div class="card card--2">
  <h2 class="card__title">
    card 2 title
  </h2>
  <p class="card__body">
    lorem ipsum
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is way over stretched. `background-color` in my question was only an example of problem. This answer is not applicable in real applications. Happy that you find hacky solution, but I'm looking for general answer for my question.