container query does not work in inline or from external css file in Astro
having below css file and imported in Astro but container query does not seem to work; also tries the :is-inline directive within .Astro file but it doesnt getting applied
panel.css
main {
  container-type: inline-size;
  container-name: main;
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1.5rem solid rgb(222, 21, 21);
  outline: 0.5rem solid khaki;
  outline-offset: 2ch;
  height: 80dvh;
  margin: 2rem;
}

@container (min-width <=200px) {
  main {
    margin: 20rem;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-color: black;
  }
}

panel.astro
---
import "panel.css";
---

<style is:inline>
  /* inline: relative & npm package imports are not supported. */
  main { 
    container-type: inline-size;
    container-name: main;
    border: 0.5rem outset pink;
    outline: 0.5rem solid khaki;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2rem skyblue;
    border-radius: 12px;
    font: bold 1rem sans-serif;
    margin-block: 5rem;
    margin-inline: 5rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    outline-offset: 0.5rem;
    height: 40dvh;
  }

</style>
<main></main>


Not sure what you are trying to do here. You can't change the container's styles with a container query. You change the styles of a child based on the container's size.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74170094/how-to-modify-css-property-of-element-with-container-type-inline-size-by-conta

Then clearly you haven't explained yourself properly.

so here we can only ask if we are able to explian properly; may be i am not able to explain at all. what is the wrong to help it out. if you do not understand then clearly said which part?

You haven't said what element you are trying to affect. If it's the main container, then as was said, you can't affect the actual container with a container query. Container queries affect the children of the container based on the container's size. That's the part you haven't explained.

I have written the HTML. there is only <main> tag ? cant we change background color based on viewport width using this?

Because you have stated the container as being main, which according to your comment it is not. The body would be the container. But you don't need a container query if you want to change styles based on viewport size, just a standard media query.

oh so media query are still applicable? I though container query can do the same job what media query can do.

You could use a container query if you specify the body as the container. A media query and a container query are similar but not the same. Again, container queries are used to style children based on the size of the container. Media queries style any element based on the size of the viewport.
